# notation convention of vectors in differential calculus and integration

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, lebesgue-integral

Recently I've been reviewing my calculus 2 materials and noticed a strange inconsistency in the notation. 
So, in differential calculus, a vector is usually noted as a column vector, but in Lebesgue-Integration, they are noted as row vectors. Is this just a convention, or is there some meaning to this im missing?

Comment: Mostly depends on the author, in my experience. It is usually well-defined within the same textbook but the issue usually arises when a lecturer in a university takes info from different textbooks with different convention.

Comment: Yeah, that was exactly my problem. and thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

Integration and differential calculus are closely releted topics and there is no reason why one should use row vectors in one and column vectors in the other. The choice between row vectors in one and column vectors  is a personal one and one can use either one in any topic.

Comment: ok, thank you for the answer! I suppose is was a pretty arbitrary change then.